# how to retrive customer orders in magento api V1

Tags: php, magento, soap

I am using magento API V1. I want to retrieve specific customer orders. I am using `order.list` method. In this method my filter is not working.It is giving me complete order list. I don't know where i am mistaking. Here is my code

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$filter = array('filter' => array(array('key=' => 'customer_id', 'value' => 210)));

$result = $client->call($session, 'order.list',$filter);
var_dump ($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a way to retrieve customer orders

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$customer_id = 210;

$result = $client->call($session, 'order.list');

if($result)
{       
foreach($result as $val)
{
  if($customer_id==$val['customer_id'])
  {
    $res[] = $val;
  }

var_dump ($res);

}
```